# Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module not sure where the error is

Tags: node.js

I keep getting this error when I try tp run the code and I don't know what's wrong with it

```
const geolib = require('geolib');
                   ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /Users/andreeacoptu/PycharmProjects/matcha/mysql-api/node_modules/geolib/lib/index.js from /Users/andreeacoptu/PycharmProjects/matcha/mysql-api/server/controlers/filtercontroler.js not supported.
index.js is treated as an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which declares all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules, or change "type": "module" to "type": "commonjs" in /Users/andreeacoptu/PycharmProjects/matcha/mysql-api/node_modules/geolib/package.json to treat all .js files as CommonJS (using .mjs for all ES modules instead).
```

This is part of the file where I keep getting the same error:

```
var getdatamodel = require('../models/getdatamodel');
var Image = require('../models/imagesmodel');
var Tag = require('../models/tagsmodel');
var Likes = require('../models/profilemodel');
var Filter = require('../models/filtermodel');
const messages = require('../models/messagesmodel');
var _ = require('lodash');
const geolib = require('geolib');

exports.usersFiltred = async (req, res) => {
    var username = req.jwt.user;
    //console.log(req.jwt);
    var resarray = [];
    var userdata = [];
    if (!username) {
        return res.json({
            success: false,
            error: 'username undefined'
        });
    } else if (!String(username).match(/^[a-z]+([_-]?[a-z0-9])*$/g) || username.length > 30) {
        return res.json({
            success: false,
            error: 'username is wrong'
        });
    }
    try {
        await Filter.user_profile(username).then(
            async (resUser) => {
                userdata.user = resUser;
                try {
                    await Filter.getUserTags(resUser[0].user_id).then(
                        async (resTags) => {
                            userdata.tags = resTags;
                        },
                        (err) => {
                            //console.log(err);
                        }
                    )
                } catch (err) { }
            },
            (err) => {
                //console.log(err);
            }
        );
    } catch (err) { /*console.log("RRRR")*/ }

    let preference;
    if (userdata.user[0].user_prefer === 'X')
        preference = '[F-M]';
    else
        preference = userdata.user[0].user_prefer;
    try {
        await Filter.getUsers(username, preference).then(
            async (res) => {
                for (const item of res) {
                    var data = {};
                    /*//console.log(item);*/
                    try {
                        await Filter.getProfilInfo(item.user_name).then(
                            async (resUser) => {
                                data.user = resUser[0];
                                data.user.isOnline = "waiting";
                                data.user.distance = parseInt(geolib.convertDistance(geolib.getDistance({ latitude: resUser[0].latitude, longitude: resUser[0].longitude },
                                    { latitude: userdata.user[0].latitude, longitude: userdata.user[0].longitude }), 'km'))
                                try {
                                    await Filter.getUserImages(resUser[0].user_id).then(
                                        async (resImgs) => {
                                            data.Images = resImgs;
                                            try {
                                                await Filter.getUserTags(resUser[0].user_id).then(
                                                    async (resTags) => {
                                                        data.tags = resTags;
                                                        data.user.communtags = _.intersectionWith(resTags, userdata.tags, _.isEqual).length;
                                                    },
                                                    (err) => {
                                                        ////console.log(err);
                                                    }
                                                );
                                            } catch (err) { }
                                        },
                                        (err) => {
                                            // //console.log(err);
                                        }
                                    )
                                } catch (err) { }
                            },
                            (err) => {
                                ////console.log(err);
                            }
                        )
                    } catch (err) { }
                    resarray.push(data);
                }
            }
        )
    } catch (err) { }
    return res.json({
        success: true,
        data: resarray
    });
```

Comment: Which part of the error message is unclear?

Comment: the whole thing I just don't know what im doing wrong

Comment: The module you are trying to import seems to be an ES module. You cannot directly `require` an ES module. The error message tells you how to fix the issue, of which I believe only *"change the requiring code to use dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules"* applies. Of course you can also write all your own modules as ES modules. For more information have a look at https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html .

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).